# Can we use Python in Numerous Event correlation for a network security purpose?

Tags: python, postgresql, correlation, complex-event-processing, network-security

We have a heavy traffic of Events log( generated by Intrusion detection systems NIDS and HIDS but no matter)
The traffic is asynchronous and the Events are not the same but each event at least has these details:
-Date & Time,
-Protocol, 
-Source IP and port,
-Destination IP and port,
-Payload and ….
We want to make a correlation engine that first, receives this event logs(for i.e. by syslog), then pars events and separate above parameters and finally the important part is that we want correlate these parameters with each other and generate new alerts.
 
*For i.e. a correlation rule could be: if a source ip repeated more than 20 times in a minute and if such a minute repeated more than 40 times a day, generate an alert.*


The big problem is the number of events that normally is **more than 30,000 events per second!!** that should be correlated by more than **100** correlation rules like above.
Previous and popular solutions are mostly written with **C/C++**, using MySQL (Maria dB) but for some reason we prefer **python** and **PostgreSQL**.
   1- First I want to know if the bottleneck is dependent or independent to programming language, database or sth else.
   2- And second, If the answer of first question is “Yes”, can **python** and postgres handle such performance for us? Is there a valid case study that has done something like this before?(or any benchmark)

Comment: Try ask on Server Fault

Comment: Server Fault would be the place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný 
No its not Network and administration issue but a programming and python question